# Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to use a physical Android device to test/debug my React Native project.

I connected the device to my Windows 11 machine via USB and turned on Developer mode on the device but when I tried to run my project, I got an error stating the following:

> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using
> Java 1.8.

I downloaded and installed Java version 11 from this URL: https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/11

I then tried to set the version through:
Android Studio > File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle > Gradle JDK

I also went into `Environment Variables` on my Windows 11 machine and pointed `JAVA_HOME` to the folder where Java version 11 is.

But no matter what I do, it doesn't work. If I run `./gradlew --version` under Android folder, I see the following:
[image]

Any suggestions how to handle this and set the correct version of Java for Gradle in my React Native project?

P.S. Even if I try to use the Android simulator on my dev machine, I now get the same error i.e. asking for Java 11. So, at this point, I'm completely unable to run any -- even a brand new -- React Native project on an Android device or the simulator.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An easier solution might be to set the `org.gradle.java.home` variable in gradle.properties file.
To do that:

1. Locate the gradle.properties file in your project directory, create one if it's not present.
2. Add the variable like this

```
org.gradle.java.home = path/to/java11
```

Remember, no quotation marks in the path. And, point it towards the Java Installation directory, and not the bin folder.

**Don't miss the double slash instead of single like below:**

```
C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.14
```

Comment: use double slashes, for eg. C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.14

Comment: @Duoro double backslashes are not needed

Comment: That's weird, without double slashes it was giving me that this is not a valid variable.

Answer (score 1):

For those running into this issue with CI/CD pipelines,
just do this

```
image: openjdk:11-jdk
```

in the yml file for your pipeline.